# App crashes after first Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

Sometimes (not very frequently) my android app crashes after first logging to facebook using Facebook Login (Facebook SDK version 3.5).

I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {my.app.package/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {my.app.package/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

with 2 different root exceptions:

Sometimes with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:135)
```

And sometimes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.logAuthorizationMethodComplete(AuthorizationClient.java:519)
```

In most cases my app is working fine.

Any ideas what may cause this problem?

EDIT:

My facebook sdk conf in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/applicationId" />
```

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

....

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initSession(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}



private void initSession(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        session.addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();


    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        session.removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

...
```

}

I also got this error with previous version of Facebook SDK. I have latest Fb android client. Any help?

Comment: ok, i added some code. Hmmm maybe it has something to do with: Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS); ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Do you manage to fix this somehow?

Comment: has this been reported on the FB developer site?

Comment: it is for example on orientation change -> onResume()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook just released v3.5.1 of their Android SDK yesterday that addresses your issues. Their [Change Log](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-3.x/) doesn't give much information about what went wrong, but people have been reporting this bug and they did say it would be fixed in a later version [(source)](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/210578742439107). But anyway, looking at the diffs between v3.5 and v3.5.1 they seem to have fixed code around lines 135 and 519. Check out the [Change Log](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master) the complete list. Probably a good idea never to upgrade to a significant version from Facebook until they release their first patch to it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today. It seems Facebook SDK 3.5 might not be compatible with old Facebook clients such as Facebook 2.1. I updated Facebook client to the latest version and then it works.

```
 09-13 17:50:43.592   11372.11372                 Bundle  W  Key com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_VERSION expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default
                                                              value <null> was returned.
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W  Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1085)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4826)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaLoginDialogAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:821)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:272)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:238)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(AuthorizationClient.java:161)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:142)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:117)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1282)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5287)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3211)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2579)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
 09-13 17:50:43.602   11372.11372                 Bundle  W     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.mycomp.myapp/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointe
                                                             rException
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3228)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2579)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4258)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:162)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:135)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:117)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1282)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5287)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3211)
 09-13 17:50:43.803   11372.11372         AndroidRuntime  E     ... 13 more
```

Comment: I don't know if its same problem as mine, root exception is diffrent :/. I also got this issue with the latest android Facebook client version...

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have same problem, however, I update the facebook sdk to 3.5.2 version from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk and any problem about loggining have been solved.